# How to insert big String into SQLite Java?

Tags: sqlite

How can I insert a string, whose length is more than 255 characters inton a single row in my database?

f.e.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\netmsg.dll (successful)
C:\e175cf64c759ffc2fb0be2d51285fbfab92c1309c23e57c511454ce4db675ae2 (successful)
C:\DOCUME~1\<USER>~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\isOGPGV.
tmp\e175cf64c759ffc2fb0be2d51285fbfab92c1309c23e57c511454ce4db675ae2.tmp (successful)
C:\DOCUME~1\<USER>~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\isH0OF3.
tmp\_isetup\_RegDLL.tmp (successful)
C:\DOCUME~1\<USER>~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\isH0OF3.
tmp\_isetup\_shfoldr.dll (successful)
C:\WINDOWS\system32\shfolder.dll (successful)
C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll (successful)
\\.\PIPE\lsarpc (successful)
\\.\MountPointManager (successful)
C:\WINDOWS\Registration\R000000000007.
```

So one String into one row in my database. Can I use BLOB for thiis? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a blob.
In SQLite, with the default settings, the [maximum length of a string](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_length) is 1000000000.